# QTableView force one cell selection

Tags: c++, qt

I want the user to be able to select only one cell at time. How can I set the maximum possible selection of cells of a QTableView to 1 (c++) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `selectionMode` to `SingleSelection` and set `selectionBehavior` to `SelectItems`

[image]

```
tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);
```